# Add Next and Prev Buttons To Rotating Banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm not knowledgeable in JS and Jquery so I'm really hoping someone here could help me out.
I want my banner to change image on page load or refresh and I found this code:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var random = document.getElementById('random');
var pictures = new Array('images/icn_slide-1.jpg','images/icn_slide-2.jpg','images/icn_slide-1.jpg','images/icn_slide-2.jpg');
var numPics = pictures.length;
if (document.images) {
    var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
    random.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
}
}
```

The script above works pretty well(background image changes every refresh) but now I want to add a previous and next button(actually I already did) so that when viewers click on next/previous it would display another image. Is there a simple way to do this? How do I make my next and previous button work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

This is the only content inside the  of my html:

```
<div id="random" style="width: 1399px; height:515px; margin:auto;">
<div id="slide_control" class="clearfix">
<span id="prev"><img alt="" title="" src="images/icn_nav-arrow2.png" /></span>
<span id="next"><img alt="" title="" src="images/icn_nav-arrow.png" /></span>
</div>
</div>
```

It's the #random div that changes background image on refresh as of now and I want it just like that. I added the "slide_control" which contained the "prev" and "next" button and what I want them to do is to also change the background-image of #random when they're clicked.

Most JS/JQquery slider and plugins comes with buttons and controllers but they auto-play images and if I disable the autoplay, they don't change banner/background on refresh.

I only want the images/background to randomly change on refresh or change when prev/next buttons are clicked but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: can you give your html for banners and buttons as well

Comment: Do you want another random image or do you want the pictures to rotate in order when clicking next/prev?

Comment: I basically want rotating banner that only change images on refresh or on click. That script I posted above is something I found by browsing, it works pretty well with changing image on refresh but didn't come w/ prev/next buttons. One more thing too, that script manipulates the background-image although i think it would be better if I'll just have a <ul> of images and make it rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of what you are asking for:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rotateImage(idx) {
    var random = document.getElementById('random');

    if (document.images) {
        random.style.background = 'url(' + pictures[idx] + ')';
        selectedImage = idx;
    }
}

function getNext() {
      var nextImage = selectedImage + 1;
      if (selectedImage >= numPics) {
          nextImage = 0;
      }
      rotateImage(nextImage);
}

function getPrev() {
      var prevImage = selectedImage - 1;
      if (selectedImage < 0) {
          selectedImage = numPics -1;
      }
      rotateImage(prevImage);
}

var pictures = new Array('images/icn_slide-1.jpg','images/icn_slide-2.jpg','images/icn_slide-1.jpg','images/icn_slide-2.jpg');
var numPics = pictures.length;
var selectedImage = null;

window.onload = function () {
     var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
     rotateImage(chosenPic);
     document.getElementById('next').onclick = getNext;
     document.getElementById('prev').onclick = getPrev;
}
</script>
```

---

Comment: Thanks kgiff, prev/next buttons are already working. But is there a way to direct them to the next or previous images when clicking? Right now, what they do is randomly rotate the image on click which means that if I click on next and back to previous, it doesn't display the previous image but randomly picks an image to display or sometimes display the same image. I want to rotate the images in order when clicking next/prev.  Or if it's easier, maybe I should just pick images in order when refreshing the page too instead of random?

Comment: modified to pick the images in order. Hopefully in a way you can follow along.